# RGBDSLAM display issues

Tags: slam, navigation, kinect, rviz, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am using RGBDSLAM on a Ubuntu 11.10 machine, with ROS Electric installed.
I am using a Kinect camera to get the video feed. When I open the rgbdslam GUI using:

**rosrun rgbdslam rgbdslam**

I can see the monochrome image and depth image, but on the top window, I am supposed to see the 'map', right? But what I see is basically the background wallpaper (the desktop) right through it. I am confused as to why this happens.

I also ran rviz, and so far it does say that I am subscribed to a pointcloud2. However, even in rviz I do not get to see a 'map' or a video feed, just a black background screen as set by default.

Can anyone help?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36717/rgbdslam-display-issues/) by [periphery](https://answers.ros.org/users/2488/periphery/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2012-06-18

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [periphery](https://answers.ros.org/users/2488/periphery/) on 2012-06-20**:
@Felix Endres : I couldn't find the use_glwidget parameter in any launchfile. Which launchfile were you talking about specifically? I am in ros/rgbdslam/launch directory.

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2012-06-20**:
Have a look at the sample config: http://alufr-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/launch/rgbdslam_sample_config.launch - It should contain all possible parameter in their default configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sounds like OpenGL problems.
Either fix these, or use rgbdslam without 3D display by setting the parameter "use_glwidget" to "false" (e.g. in a launchfile).

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2012-06-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0